# Указывает на ошибку в строковом ресурсе из-за нескольких символов "%"

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть в файле стрингс.хмл ресурс, содержащий такую строку:

```
    <string name="Help_report_period6">
    % = ( 2 часа / 22 часа ) * 100% = 9.1%.
    </string>
```

Опытным путем нашел этот кусок строки, который дает ошибку - неожидаемый тэг. По частям строка проходит без ошибок. Где здесь нарушены святые письмена?
Все дело в использовании символа % больше одного раза. Что можно сделать, чтобы и символ показать, и ошибки избежать?

Comment: Clean-build делали?

Comment: Возможно, какие-то библиотеки конфликтуют. Может даже стандартная с чем-то. Убедитесь, что добавляете стандартную библиотеку один раз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить аттрибут `formatted="false"` в объявление строки. т.е.
 `<string name="Help_report_period6" formatted="false">`

Comment: Помогло, только правильное написание: formatted="false", т.е. с двумя аглицкими t.

Comment: @St-st, поправил в ответе)